# How to do dynamodb pagination in lambda function with nodejs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want the frontend to decide the currentPage, pageSize(number of data in a page) and the sorting(+ mean ascending/- mean descending) in event.queryStringParameters.

**Dynamodb attribute**
-id(string)(partition key) 
-createdAt(date) 
-url(string) 
-createdBy(string) 
-title(string)

But I am troubled to create this function, I can only set the pageSize, and I don't know how to deal with currentPage and sorting in my function.

Below is my current lambda function.
getBanner.js

```
'use strict'
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async function (event, context, callback) {
    const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    let responseBody = "";
    let statusCode = 0;

    const queryParams = JSON.stringify(event.queryStringParameters);

    /* queryParams will look like this
     {
       "currentPage": "0",
       "pageSize": "30",
       "sorting": "-status"
     }
    */

    const params = {
        TableName : "Banner",
        Limit:queryParams.pageSize
    };

    try{
        const data = await documentClient.scan(params).promise();
        responseBody = JSON.stringify(data.Items);
        statusCode = 200
    }catch(err){
        responseBody = `Unable to get Alerts: ${err}`;
        statusCode = 403
    }

    const response = {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        headers:{
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // Required for CORS support to work
        },
        body: responseBody
    }

    return response
}
```

Comment: You need to go back to design your DynamoDB my friend. If need a chat, let me know

Comment: Can you explain more? Thanks

Comment: To do pagination, we need to have a design. Do you have it with you? If yes, I can review and see if it works

Comment: Updated above. Thank you so much

Comment: With that design, how can you implement pagination?  Please draft your logic

Answer (score 3):

Pagination doesn't work that way in DynamoDB ([link to docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.Pagination.html)).  This is another example of where knowledge of SQL database practices can hinder your understanding of DynamoDB.

DynamoDB has a limit of 1MB responses for `scan` and `query` operations.  Anything larger than that will be paginated.  This means that DynamoDB will paginate results on the size of the response, not the number of items in the response.  This limitation ensures that your responses stay small and manageable, while your queries remain performant.

Fetching 1MB of data at a time is different than fetching `N` rows at a time, as is common with pagination in SQL databases.  Take some time to read up on how DDB handles pagination with the `LastEvaluatedKey` and `ExclusiveStartKey` before implementing a front-end solution.